# Python: How do I print an unicode string from a .txt file

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, file-manipulation

I'm using Python 3.2.3 and idle to program a text game.
I'm using a .txt file to store the map schemes that later will be opened by the program and draw at the terminal(IDLE for the moment).

What is in the .txt file is it:

```
╔════Π═╗
Π      ║ 
║w bb c□
║w bb c║ 
╚═□══□═╝
```

Π: door; □: window; b: bed; c: computer; w: wardrobe

As I'm new to programming I'm having a difficult problem doing this.

Here is the code I made so far for this:

```
doc =  codecs.open("D:\Escritório\Codes\maps.txt")
map = doc.read().decode('utf8')
whereIsmap = map.find('bedroom')
if buldIntel == 1 and localIntel == 1:
    whereIsmap = text.find('map1:')
    itsGlobal = 1
if espLocation == "localIntel" == 1:
    whereIsmap = text.find('map0:')
if buldIntel == 0 and localIntel == 0:
    doc.close()

for line in whereIsmap:
    (map) = line
    mapa.append(str(map))
doc.close()

if itsGlobal == 1:
    print(mapa[0])
    print(mapa[1])
    print(mapa[2])
    print(mapa[3])
    print(mapa[4])
    print(mapa[5])
    print(mapa[6])
    print(mapa[7])

if itsLocal == 1 and itsGlobal == 0:
    print(mapa[0])
    print(mapa[1])
    print(mapa[2])
    print(mapa[3])
    print(mapa[4])
```

There are two maps and each one of them has a title the smaller one is map1(the one I've show).

Python is giving this error message if I try to run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\projetoo", line 154, in <module>
    gamePlay(ask1, type, selfIntel1, localIntel, buildIntel, whereAmI, HP, time, itsLocal, itsBuild)
  File "C:\Python32\projetoo", line 72, in gamePlay
    map = doc.read().decode('utf8')
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What do I do to print to the IDLE terminal the maps exactly as I showed up there?

Comment: Are you sure your file is utf-8? Files starting with `\xff` most of the time are utf-16.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `codecs.open` without specifying an encoding, then trying to decode the string returned by `doc.read()`, even though it is already a Unicode string.

To fix this, specify an encoding in your call to `codecs.open`: `codecs.open("...", encoding="utf-8")`, then you won't need the call to `.decode('utf-8')` later.

Also, since you're using Python 3, you can just use `open`:

```
doc = open("...", encoding="utf-8").read()
```

Finally, you'll need to re-encode the unicode string when you print it:

```
print("\n".join(mapa[0:4]).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Got it. But what means "\n". I never used this code. What should I put there?

Comment: print(u"\n".join(mapa[0:4]).encode("utf-8")) this code is outputting an error "invalid sintax" just after "\n at the (") signal.

Comment: Oh, are you using Python3? If so, use `print("\n".join(mapa[0:4]).encode("utf-8"))`. I think.

Comment: And `"\n"` is the newline character. To see what it does: `print("foo\nbar")`

Comment: Got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\projetoo", line 149, in <module>
    gamePlay(ask1, type, selfIntel1, localIntel, buildIntel, whereAmI, HP, time, itsLocal, itsBuild)
  File "C:\Python32\projetoo", line 72, in gamePlay
    whereIsmap = map.find('bedroom')
  File "C:\Python32\lib\codecs.py", line 721, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: I think I'll just redraw the map in ASCII it wont be perfect but at least it's going to work. What do you think?

Comment: Err, sorry, I accidentally a `.read()` in that example. Fixed now.

Comment: It's still giving a error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`. Also, sorry for the bottering.

Comment: Ah, so in that case, you might need to follow @mata's suggestion and try using `utf-16` instead of `utf-8`.

Comment: It worked with `utf-16`, now I'm having an issue with this code `for line in searchMap:
            (mapa) = line
            mapa.append(str(mapa))

        if itsGlobal == 1:
            print(mapa[0])
            print(mapa[1])
            print(mapa[2])
            print(mapa[3])
            print(mapa[4])
            print(mapa[5])
            print(mapa[6])
            print(mapa[7])` It prints: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`